# Where can I make changes to view's bounds in IOS 6

Tags: ios6, interface-builder, autolayout

Before IOS 6 the right place to do that would be viewWillAppear:, because everything was already loaded and set from interface builder, but now, the frame still changes after viewWillAppear:.

The only other place that I can think to put this kind of code would be in viewDidAppear:, but if I do that, the user will see the screen suddenly changing just after the view appears.

So what can I do?

Thank you.

Btw, frame also changes after viewDidLayoutSubviews:, so it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Your theory on where to do layout changes is not incorrect and most likely does not change under iOS6.  What does change is that if you are using autolayout, you nolonger make changes to frame or bounds, autolayout does that for you.  You now make changes to the constraints.  When you change the constraints then things like frame are automatically done for you.

Comment: I didn't manage to get autolayout working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412012/subview-disappears-with-auto-layout

So I'm not using it.
But I still get the same problem.